# How to Use "EVO suite" for Android unit tests generation.

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, evosuite

I have an Android project, For which I need to generate Unit tests.
So Instead of writing them, I found that we can automatically generate unit tests by EVOsuite.
Info provided in the official documentation of EVOSuite is not sufficient, and plugin provided in the official site doesn't work. So, Are there any one who used EVO tests suite for Unit tests Generation.

I am refering to "http://www.evosuite.org/"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quoting an [issue](https://github.com/EvoSuite/evosuite/issues/87) in GitHub:

> In principle, it should be possible to generate tests for Android
>   projects given the JVM bytecode. However, it is my understanding that
>   in this case the Android API consists only of stubs and thus wouldn't
>   lead to useful tests.